# Inheritance and Friends: Safety mechanism?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, friend

I came across an interesting theory and I was wondering whether there is a safety mechanism in c++ against this.

```
class Base
{
 private:
 virtual void a(){};
 friend class C;
}

class Derived: public Base
{
void a() override {};
}

class C{

public doSomething(const Base& b) {b.a();};

}
```

All of this is legal - class C is a friend of base and thus can call b.a(). However, as it received a reference, it can receive a reference to a Derived object and thus C would be accessing the private area in class Derived, without being a friend of derived.

Is this simply bad code design or is there a safe guard against this? Happened to me when overriding operator<< for the base, and calling a general print function from inside (the operator was a friend of the base).

Comment: In C++ you have friends so that you can get at their private parts.

Comment: the way to visualise this is that the derived class's access specifiers apply to accesses via lvalues of its static type and by its descendents - rather than being able retroactively to alter the access specifiers that its base declared for access through basal lvalues, which be at least bad, possibly absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the skeleton of the design (of Base and Derived) stands, this is a typical good design that was advocated by Herb Sutter [15 years ago](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) - except that making class C friend is superfluous, since it can call the public function run(). C will need to be friend only if it needs to use only a(), in case run() has more functionality to be avoided (and I would suspect a bad design in such a case).
I wondered what was wrong with my reading, because, unlike the previous answers, I don't see that a() is public, nor do I see that Base is a private base.
Enjoy

Comment: The link in the answer provides the exact explanation - I would recommend reading it to anyone who is interested

Answer (score 4):

There are no safeguards needed here. This is how C++ works by design.

By overriding a virtual function in the base class, the derived class reimplements it. But the definition of "reimplementing" includes inheriting all the baggage from the base class. Including the fact that the virtual function in the base class is `public` in this case.

The fact that the derived class defines the reimplemented function as `private` does not change the fact that it's overriding a public function. And, as such, it should expect it to still be reachable via the base class.

At most, I suppose, you can call this a "quirk". The bottom line is that if you're overriding a `public` virtual function, the process of overriding doesn't change the fact that it's a public function. Making the overriding function "private", in the derived class, is closing the barn after the horses have already left.

And you have to be aware of the fact that you are overriding a public virtual function. In some situation I'd say this can even be a feature. It wouldn't be too hard to imagine a situation where a particular base class function should only be called by the existing code that directly references the base class. Any code that has a pointer or a reference to the derived class is higher level code that should not have any business calling the base class's functions. This would be one way to do this, of course. This certainly isn't meant to be iron-tight security of some kind, but merely a mechanism for the compiler to help you catch logical or functional errors, or design errors of some kind.

Comment: I think an easier way to visualise this is that the derived class's access specifier applies to accesses via lvalues of its static type and by its descendents, rather than retroactively being able to alter the specifications of its base, which would of course be absurd.

Comment: And ... *(shrug)* "what are 'friends' for?" ... Yeah, they're the ones who drive you home from the party, then pretend the next day that you were never drunk. In C++, the notion of "friend" is: "someone that we can *trust* to get by with a nod and a knowing wink." A "friend" is ... shall we say ... a bit of a *compatriot.*  A "sometimes-very-necessary evil ..."

Comment: A `friend` of a C++ class is, informally, something that class trusts sufficiently to have granted unfettered access to all of its private, protected, and public parts.   So, arguably, a C++ class trusts all its friends more than people trust theirs.

Answer (score 4):

Well, no, this is not bad design of C++.  It is bad design of your program.

A program which does something like

```
 some_C.doSomething(some_derived);
```

will fail to compile.    This is because your `Base` is a private base of `Derived`.    So the conversion of a `Derived &` to a `Base &` is invalid.

The exception to the above is if the calling function which does this is either a member or a `friend` of `Derived`.   In that case, the behaviour is controlled by the (developer of) `Derived`, if you have done such a thing, it is solely your responsibility.